# Issue while uploading file to the database as form using springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

The functionality should be the user should upload the book to db. The information which is obtained from the form should be uploaded to the data base but i dont know where i went wrong. Please help me with the issue.

```
package com.elibrary.elib.entity;
    
    import jakarta.persistence.*;
    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.Data;
    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
    
    @Entity
    @Data
    @Table(name = "books")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Books {
        @Id
        private String bookId;
        private String title;
        private String subject;
        private String department;
        private String keyword;
        private String author;
        private String uploadedBy;
        @Lob
        @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
        private byte[] file;
    }
```

This is my entity code which is designed to store the information

```
        public String uploadFile(String bookId, String title, String subject, String department, String keyword, String author, String uploadedBy, byte[] byteFile) {
            Books book = new Books();
            book.setBookId(bookId);
            book.setTitle(title);
            book.setSubject(subject);
            book.setDepartment(department);
            book.setKeyword(keyword);
            book.setAuthor(author);
            book.setUploadedBy(uploadedBy);
            book.setFile(byteFile);
            bookRepositry.save(book);
            return "File uploaded successfully";
        }
```

This is my service class to upload a file to the db by the admin or faculty.

```
        public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, IOException {
            String bookId = request.getParameter("bookId");
            String title = request.getParameter("title");
            String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
            String department = request.getParameter("department");
            String keyword = request.getParameter("keyword");
            String author = request.getParameter("author");
            String uploadedBy = request.getParameter("uploadedBy");
            byte[] byteFile = file.getBytes();
            return bookService.uploadFile(bookId, title, subject, department, keyword, author, uploadedBy, byteFile);
        }
```

This is my controller function and I am facing error while i am passing the data using postman.[I am facing this er](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb8wa.png) SQL Error: 1406, SQLState: 22001

```
    2023-05-06T23:23:33.635+05:30 ERROR 25753 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Data truncation: Data too long for column 'file' at row 1
```

Comment: Have you checked what is the actual column type which is created in the database by JPA? Probably it is not LONGBLOB, but something different